# What is meaning of 0 in mysql_result($res, 0, "id");?

Tags: php

I searched on google but didn't find anything that could help me!

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($u) ."' ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) 
{
$id = mysql_result($res, 0, "id");        // got id of username
}
```

What does 0 represents?

Comment: Have you checked [`the reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

The 0 represents the first row of data in the array (as the array indexes begin at 0), I assume so it returns the ID of the first username it comes across, regardless of how many it finds.

If you have any more questions on built-in PHP functions, it's best you look at the [PHP reference manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) first.

Answer (score 0):

The row number from the result that's being retrieved. Row numbers start at 0.

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score -1):

Array's number `$res['0'];`

Arrays starts with 0.